# Pattern Recognition - Chess Tactics

Tags: analysis, tactics, training

I have a collection of ten thousand games of a player.
Is there a way to look which kind of tactics does the player miss on most often?

Which tactics does he need to focus on?

Comment: tactics generators? eg http://chesstacticsgenerator.vitomd.com/ i think there's some like open source thing on lichess or github (or lichess linking to github) that you can modify to help you out. maybe stackoverflow can help as well. anyhoo if anyone has better answers, i'd like to know (now clicking follow)

Comment: This gives individual games - what i am looking for is analysis across games and various patterns that players play well and play poorly.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new lichess account. Import the games into the new account. Run AimChess on it. You will then statistics about the player.

Comment: Note: get permission from mods/admins 1st re the new account